# Turning a combobox to a string

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, jcombobox

so I'm trying to edit a column in my table using

```
gender.setText(beingEdited.getGender());
```

gender is a `ComboBox` and there error I get is

```
cannot find symbol
symbol:   method setText(String)
location: variable gender of type JComboBox
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)
```

How can I fix this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use [setValueAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setValueAt%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) instead. The `JComboBox` `CellEditor` will be updated with the new value

```
myTable.setValue(beingEdited.getGender(), row, column);
```